# Display different Actions - LWC lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an LWC with several tabs of opportunity data that differ by record type.  Right now, each tab has a lightning-datatable with a different record type displayed.  Some of these opportunity types should have different actions as they need to navigate to a different place.  Is there a way to show different actions on the different tabs without creating a whole new set of actions/columns?

In the code below, I would want to display Sales Opp Wizard on some tabs but show Wellness Opp WIzard on others.

Thanks!!

```
//actions available in data-table
    const actions = [
        { label: 'Sales Opp Wizard', name: 'Sales_Opp_Wizard' },
        { label: Wellness Opp Wizard', name: 'SL_Team_Opp_Wizard' },
        { label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' },
        { label: 'Edit', name: 'edit_record' },
        { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' },
      ];
    
       //variable to hold all but dental columns
       const columns = [
        {label: 'Actions', type: 'action', fixedWidth: 70, fixedHeight: 200,
        typeAttributes: {
          rowActions: actions,
          menuAlignment: 'auto'
        }
        },
          { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', sortable: "true", initialWidth: 450,
          cellAttributes: {
            class: { fieldName: 'activeClass'}
          }},
          { label: 'Stage', fieldName: 'StageName',sortable: "true", initialWidth: 140,
          cellAttributes: {
            class: { fieldName: 'activeClass'}
          }},
          { label: 'Eff Date', fieldName: 'CloseDate', type: 'date-local', sortable: "true", initialWidth: 110,
          cellAttributes: {
            class: { fieldName: 'activeClass'}
         
      ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need separate lists, but you can build those lists from other lists:

```
const salesOppWizardAction = [ { label: 'Sales Opp Wizard', name: 'Sales_Opp_Wizard' } ];
const wellnessOppWizardAction = [ { label: Wellness Opp Wizard', name: 'SL_Team_Opp_Wizard' } ];
const otherActions = [
    { label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' },
    { label: 'Edit', name: 'edit_record' },
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' },
  ];
const tab1Actions = [ ...salesOppWizardAction, ...otherActions];
const tab2Actions = [ ...wellnessOppWizardAction, ...otherActions];
```